# How can i resolve my external HDD boot issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I cloned my windows 10 to a partitioned external HDD and then did a full install of Ubuntu 22.04 to the HDD which is setup as GPT and has a 2mb partition at the beginning flagged for grub/bios and a 300mb partition formatted fat32 and flagged as boot/esp for efi. When booting up my laptop with the drive connected via USB my internal grub boot menu lists the external OS along with the installed OS but when selected for boot I get error messages the kernel isn't loaded.

Comment: Is Internal install UEFI or BIOS? You should not mix UEFI & BIOS and never mix UEFI & BIOS on same drive. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Note that MIcrosoft does not allow full installs of Windows booting from removable devices.

Comment: My laptop isn't UEFI capable

Comment: Http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YpcgcwbTz2/

Comment: You have UEFI system, but BIOS installs. Is UEFI version (Line 171) latest from Dell? Only use Boot-Repair's advanced mode & choose install in sdb and install grub to sdb drive. Boot-Repair is suggesting an UEFI install of grub which may work on sdb, but then grub would only find other UEFI installs. Best not to mix UEFI & BIOS.